# Method in a contraint

Tags: constraints, cplex

I've a cplex constraint in the form of a a binary variable multiply for a number >= to another number.
The second number is complex to calculate, I think I need a method to compute it, it is possible in cplex write a constraint like this:

```
k*y[i] > method(parameter1,parameter2)
```

In the method I need to access to binary variables values.
Thanks a lot for replies.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try this [oulipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo) challenge.

> Write an OPL models that works and that contains what you wrote.

Could this help?

```
float k=1.2;
dvar boolean y[1..1];
int parameter1=1;
int parameter2=2;
dvar boolean x;
dexpr float method[i in 1..10,j in 1..10]=x*(i+j);

subject to
{
forall(i in 1..1)
  k*y[i] >= method[parameter1,parameter2];
}
```

PS: with your later comments:

```
float k=1.2;
dvar boolean y[1..1];
int parameter1=1;
int parameter2=2;
dvar boolean x;
float methodresults[i in 1..10,j in 1..10]; //=x*(i+j);
range r=1..10;
execute
{
function method(i,j)
{
return i+j;
}

for(var i in r) for (var j in r) methodresults[i][j]=method(i,j);
}


subject to
{
forall(i in 1..1)
  k*y[i] >= x*methodresults[parameter1,parameter2];
}
```

Comment: Maybe It's my fault to explain bad the question I would a function in which I can use for construct and acces to variable of the model and other stuff like a classical language, I need this to compute an integer value for the constraint

Comment: Yes, "method" is a function that computes a float out of i,j and decision variable x

Comment: Yes, but seems is not possible write things like this:

Comment: method =  and put into this if statement or for statement.

Comment: You could use the ternary operator for the "if" and sum for the "for". Example : dexpr float method[i in 1..10,j in 1..10]=(i==3)?x*(i+j):sum(k in 1..4)x;

Comment: I don't need ever to sum in my for. I apologize for my low experience in opl, but the question is there is a way to define a method function in which I can have the syntax used for example in the execute section of opl script?

Comment: Hi, if you need to define your function in javascript then you may have to compute a full set of values in an execute block before the subject to block. Anyway similar discussion at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f8e5ede2-8b7a-48da-b83c-d911edfbda32&ps=25

Comment: Hi, thanks for replies, but I can't compute a full set of values, because there are too many and my function is complex. Methaforical speaking I need a function that calculate the height of a pile, like an abacus, in which I've inserted pieces, but the pieces could not be ever in contact, could be some holes in the pile, to understand if I have some holes I need to see to adiacent piles. So it if very difficult to calculate this in linear programming, and I don't know if it is permitted, but afterall is only a number, so I think could be define a simple function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a script in a `.mod` file, then you can define a function whithin an `execute` block [1]. These blocks define pre-processing or post-processing instructions written in ILOG Script [2]. Here's a trivial example from the documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllangref/topics/opl_langref_script_struct_statements_function.html.

```
execute {
   function add(a, b) {
       return a+b
   }
   writeln(add(1,2));
}
```

[1] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_script_intro_presynt.html

[2] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_script.html

Comment: Mmmm, I don't understand where insert this definition, for example, I cut and past this in my model where variables are defined and I get an error. Another things maybe It's my fault to explain bad the question I would a function in which I can use for construct and acces to variable of the model and other stuff like a classical language, I need this to compute an integer value for the constraint

Comment: I updated my answer to give more information about ILOG Script, which is similar to JavaScript.